# Calculating the integral $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos (kx)}{x^2+a^2} dx$ as an double integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I want to calculate:  $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos (kx)}{x^2+a^2} \tag{1}  $$ 
Therefore I can use:  $$\frac{x}{a^2+x^2}=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ay}\sin (xy)dy \tag{2}$$
$2 \ in \  1  $ leads to:
 $$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos kx}{a^2+x^2}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos kx}{x}dx\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ay}\sin (xy)dy.$$
Changing the order of integration yields( I'm not sure how to justify that. Maybe I can use Fubini/Tonelli ?!):
$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ay}dy\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin xy}{x} \cos kx dx. $$

I know: $$ \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x} dx = \frac{\pi}{2}  \tag{3}$$

How can I use $3$ to calculate  $$ \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin xy}{x} \cos kx dx. $$

Comment: After $(2)$ what you have written doesn't make any sense as the integral $\int_0^\infty (\cos{(kx)}/x) \mathrm{d}x$ does not converge.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to make your method work, but this integral is fairly straightforward using complex analysis if you have those tools available. Define $$f(z) = \frac{e^{ikz}}{z^2+a^2}.$$ Then $f$ has poles of order $1$ at $x = \pm ia$. Then use the residue theorem with a semicircular contour (the sign of $k$ will inform you as to whether the semicircle needs to be in the upper or lower half plane).

Comment: I have to do it that way. I have tp transform the integral in a double integral.

Comment: @PeterForeman $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin xy}{x} \cos kx dx$ This one should converge, but I'm not sure wether Im allowed to to shift cos(kx) in the other integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the integral:
$$I(k) := \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos(k\,x)}{x^2 + a^2}\,\text{d}x $$
with $a,\,k > 0$, differentiating under the integral sign, we have:
$$I'(k) = \int_0^{\infty} -\frac{x\,\sin(k\,x)}{x^2 + a^2}\,\text{d}x \,.$$
Now, adding both members as follows:
$$I'(k) + b = \int_0^{\infty} -\frac{x\,\sin(k\,x)}{x^2 + a^2}\,\text{d}x + \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(k\,x)}{x}\,\text{d}x\,, $$
where $b$ is known but we don't care, we get:
$$I'(k) + b = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{a^2\,\sin(k\,x)}{x\left(x^2 + a^2\right)}\,\text{d}x$$
and therefore it's again possible differentiating under the integral sign, obtaining:
$$I''(k) = a^2\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos(k\,x)}{x^2 + a^2}\,\text{d}x\,,$$
ie:
$$I''(k) = a^2\,I(k)\,.$$
Solving this differential equation, we have:
$$I(k) = c_1\,e^{a\,k} + c_2\,e^{-a\,k}$$
where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are two constants to be determined.

In particular, noting that:
$$|I(k)| \le I(0) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2 + a^2}\,\text{d}x = \frac{\pi}{2\,a}$$
it follows trivially that:
$$I(k) = 0\cdot e^{a\,k} + \frac{\pi}{2\,a}\cdot e^{-a\,k}\,,$$
ie:
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos(k\,x)}{x^2 + a^2}\,\text{d}x = \frac{\pi}{2\,a}\,e^{-a\,k}\,,$$
as we wanted to prove.

---

A slightly different way is to remember that:
$$\frac{a^2}{x^2 + a^2} = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\frac{x}{a}\,y}\,\sin y\,\text{d}y$$
$$\frac{x}{x^2 + k^2} = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x\,y}\,\cos (k\,y)\,\text{d}y$$
with $a,\,k,\,x > 0$, then:
$$I(k) = \frac{1}{a^2}\int_0^{\infty} \cos(k\,x)\,\text{d}x \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\frac{x}{a}\,y}\,\sin y\,\text{d}y$$
ie:
$$I(k) = \frac{1}{a^2}\int_0^{\infty} e^{-\frac{y}{a}\,x}\,\cos(k\,x)\,\text{d}x \int_0^{\infty} \sin y\,\text{d}y$$
from which:
$$I(k) = \frac{1}{a^2}\,\int_0^{\infty} \frac{(y/a)\,\sin y}{(y/a)^2 + k^2}\,\text{d}y = -\frac{1}{a} \int_0^{\infty} -\frac{x\,\sin(k\,x)}{x^2 + a^2}\,\text{d}x\,,$$
ie:
$$I(k) = -\frac{1}{a}\,I'(k)\,.$$
Solving this differential equation, we have:
$$I(k) = c_1\,e^{-a\,k}$$
and since:
$$I(0) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2 + a^2}\,\text{d}x = \frac{\pi}{2\,a}$$
it follows trivially that:
$$I(k) = \frac{\pi}{2\,a}\cdot e^{-a\,k}\,,$$
ie:
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos(k\,x)}{x^2 + a^2}\,\text{d}x = \frac{\pi}{2\,a}\,e^{-a\,k}\,,$$
as we wanted to prove.

Comment: Thank you for showing your way. The transformation to an differential equation is really amazing:)

Comment: How can I justify that I can change the order of integration, when I consider my calculation.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are amazing:)

Answer (score 3):

FYI, be careful with how you write your integrals. You've written them to appear like a product of two integrals, whereas you want them to be an iterated integral. See below for the correct way to write that.

Anyways, to answer your question,

> $$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ay}\left[\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin xy}{x} \cos (kx) dx\right] dy. $$
>
> I know: $$ \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x} dx = \frac{\pi}{2}  \tag{3}$$
>
> How can I use $3$ to calculate  $$ \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin xy}{x} \cos kx dx. $$

The key is the product-to-sum identity
$$
\sin(xy)\cos(kx) = \frac{\sin([y+k]x)+\sin([y-k]x)}{2}
$$
combined with a change of variables:
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(rx)}{x}dx = \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(\mathrm{sgn}(r)|r|x)}{|r|x}|r|dx = \mathrm{sgn}(r)\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(u)}{u}du = \frac{\pi}{2}\mathrm{sgn}(r).
$$
$\mathrm{sgn}$ is the signum function, which is $1$ for positive numbers, $-1$ for negative numbers, and $0$ for $0$. Putting these together gives
$$
I=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ay}\left[\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin xy}{x} \cos (kx) dx\right] dy = \int_0^\infty e^{-ay}\left[\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin([y+k]x)+\sin([y-k]x)}{2x}dx\right]dy \\= \int_0^\infty e^{-ay}\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\left[\mathrm{sgn}(y+k)+\mathrm{sgn}(y-k)\right]\right)dy = \frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^{|k|}e^{-ay}dy = \frac{\pi}{2a}e^{-|k|a}
$$

As for Fubini's theorem, it's not strictly speaking justified here as the double integral isn't absolutely convergent. It is absolutely convergent on every finite subset of the region of integration, though, which might be enough.

Comment: Thank you very much:) That's the way I wanted to go in the first place.  THe only thing I didn't understand is: "The key is the product-to-sum identity "  Which theorem are you applying in detail?

Comment: @Leon1998 The [product-to-sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities) identities are basic trig identities and a consequence of the angle addition formulae.

Comment: Thank you very much:)